# Is @NonNull annotation of Lombok allows the default constructor to give null values?

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class say C

```
class C {
  @NonNull
  private String str;
  //getters
  //setters
}
```

Now I did something like this :

```
C ob = new C();
System.out.println(ob.getStr());
```

To my surprise it printed null.

However, it gave Null pointer exception when I did:

```
ob.setStr(null)
```

Does `@NonNull` does not hold on default constructors? Please explain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does @NonNull does not hold on default constructors?

Indeed no, it doesn't, and I don't see how it could.  When a default constructor is provided by the compiler, that happens during compilation, *after* annotation processing.

Moreover, [Lombok's own docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) have this to say of that annotation's use with fields:

> Lombok has always treated any annotation named `@NonNull` on a field as
>   a signal to generate a null-check ***if lombok generates an entire method
>   or constructor for you***, via for example @Data. Now, however, using
>   lombok's own `@lombok.NonNull` on a parameter results in the insertion
>   of just the null-check statement inside ***your own*** method or
>   constructor.

That is, the annotation has effect only on your own constructors and methods (i.e. those present in your source code) and those Lombok generates for you.  A default constructor provided by the compiler is neither.

Comment: You imply its a technical matter, but way more important than that, it just doesn't make sense to have that check on a default constructor because it will literally always fail.

Comment: It *is* a technical matter, @Michael.  Just because you don't see any use in the default constructor always failing doesn't imply that the OP's annotation can't or shouldn't produce that effect.  I mean, suppose I provide my own no-arg constructor whose body unconditionally throws `NullPointerException`.  Surely you wouldn't argue that the NPE should not be thrown after all.

Comment: If the default constructor always fails, make it private. Why on earth would you ever want a method that never does anything?

Comment: @Michael, better would be to ensure that the constructor does not fail unnecessarily in the first place, but that's beside the point.  Again, just because you would not like the default constructor to always throw does not mean that you can *rely* on it not being implemented that way, whether because of code you write yourself or because of code generated during annotation processing.  You are attempting to infer behavior based on your personal position on a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: I have literally no idea what you're talking about. If Lombok were to enforce `NotNull` fields in the default constructor **whether its technically possible or not**, this would 100% of the time create a completely useless constructor. It is a feature that no one would ever want or use because it **does not make sense**.

Comment: @Michael, you're right, it would have that effect.  That's a relevant observation, but whether it makes sense (to you) for that result to be produced has no deterministic or reliably predictive effect on whether the software *will* produce that result.  If we took your apparent argument to the extreme, we could observe that it does not make sense for software to have bugs of any kind.  Should we conclude that we can rely on software not to be buggy?  Of course not.  And neither can we draw the conclusion you seem to want to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull)...

> Lombok has always treated any annotation named @NonNull **on a field** as
>   a signal **to generate a null-check if lombok generates an entire method
>   or constructor for you**, via for example @Data.

You are using the default constructor, so Lombok is not generating a constructor for you, therefore there is no null check.

---

If it did what you were expecting, every default constructed object of your class:

```
C ob = new C();
```

would immediately result in a null pointer exception. Not exactly very useful.