# Extra column being created when I use same column name for two different tables connected through ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have SpringBoot project with Spring Data. Extra column being created when I use the same column name for 2 tables mapped using ManyToOne Relation. I have Address table with column name 'id' and AddressType table with column 'id'. When I start the Spring Boot application with this, I see an extra column (address_id) created on Address table.

Address.java

```
package com.springtesting.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "street_name")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "apartment")
    private String apartment;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_type_id")
    private AddressType addressType;

    public Address()
    {
    }

    public Address(String streetName, String apartment, String city, String state, String country, String zipCode, AddressType addressType)
    {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.apartment = apartment;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.country = country;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.addressType = addressType;
    }
}
```

and

AddressType.java

```
package com.springtesting.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "address_type")
public class AddressType
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @NonNull
    private String type;

    public AddressType()
    {

    }

    public AddressType(String type)
    {
    }
}
```

when I start the Spring Boot application, I see extra column (address_id)

[Table Structure on Mysql](https://imgur.com/a/s6N4zzC)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will fix your issue, but try changing the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, or give it a "native" `GenericGenerator`, as discussed [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/). Apparently `GenerationType.AUTO` does not play nice with MySQL from Hibernate 5+.

A couple of other notes:

- You probably don't want to use Lombok's `@NonNull`, instead just use `@Column(name = "type", nullable = false)`. In fact if the POJO is created through the default constructor, Lombok's `@NonNull` [wouldn't do anything anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292453/is-nonnull-annotation-of-lombok-allows-the-default-constructor-to-give-null-val) since it's annotated over a field.
- You don't need the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` above the AddressType since you probably don't want to accidentally update/delete/or create new `AddressType`s through the `Address` entity. Just annotating it `@ManyToOne` should be enough.